# Does doPost encrypts URL and its externally appended paramaters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a small doubt regarding the working of doPost which i have never tried before.
I have created a web application with a third party application integrated in it. I am appending the username and password, to the URL which i am redirecting to the third party party application which authenticates the credentials at their end. The thrid party does not need the username and password to be encrypted or encoded and hence I am trying to use a Servlet, where doPost actually encrypts this URL.

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletRequest response)
              {
               Userdetails=//Username and password I am getting from Database using Dao
               String URL= URL.append(Userdetails)
               response.sendRedirect(URL)
              }
```

I like to know whether the above doPost encrypts the above URL mainly, the Username and password appended to it.

Additionally I want to know whether response.sendRedirect(url) encodes the URL or its parameters and sends it to the other server.

Comment: Have you run this code? It should result in an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doPost will not encrypt the URL for you and even if it were to do that, the browser won't be able to use the encrypted URL.

What should have been done is this:

1. The 3rd party app should share an API key with you.
2. You should make a server side call to obtain a one-time key corresponding to a username. The 3rd party app makes a record of the username corresponding to this one-time key.
3. Then you should send a redirect to your user's browser with that one-time key.
4. The 3rd party app should match that one-time key with the recorded username and provide the required services.

Of course, you should talk to your app provider and figure out a secure way of transacting with them.

Comment: So is it that the doPost hides the credentials only when the user parameters are sent from a form, and by post method.

Comment: No, not even that. Browsers hide the credentials when the user is posting to the server. doPost() just uses the posted data to do whatever it's that needs to be done.

Comment: Can we send the user details by appending to the header. Please can you clear your above comment.

Comment: Even if you send the user details in the header, the modern browsers have made it very easy for someone to inspect the request/response headers and see their values.

Answer (score 0):

The url does not get encrypted even when you are using secure connection (like https). Instead you can put the user name and password as part of post parameters and use a secure connection.

Comment: Can you clarify me the putting of username and password as a part of post parameters. I dont have login page, I am just appending the details which i got it from DB and sending it to the third party which they get it

Comment: I dont know what language are you using but here is java code using apache http post
<br/>
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("YOUR_URL");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
          "abdc"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
          "1243"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);